# Rails 3 merging similar instances in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models. order and line_item.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :products, :through => :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product
end
```

`line_items` include the following attributes - `:product_id`, `:size`, `:quantity`.

It's possible that an order can have more than one line_item for the same product and size, in which case, I want to be able to access the line_items merged into one with the quantity being the total of all of them. For example, an order might have the following line_items:

```
# | product_id | size   | quantity
1 | 1          | small  | 1
2 | 1          | small  | 2
3 | 1          | medium | 1
4 | 2          | small  | 1
```

Which should be merged to:

```
# | product_id | size   | quantity
1 | 1          | small  | 3
2 | 1          | medium | 1
3 | 2          | small  | 1
```

It seems natural to me that this should either be a scope or a class method on the order model, so I can call `@order.line_items_merged` or something similar from the view, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it really make sense to have multiple line items for the same (product, size) pair? Will you actually ever use them separately, or only merged?

Personally I would consider changing the logic so that you *can't* have more than one line item for the same product and size (i.e. incrementing quantity directly, rather creating multiple records to merge), and thus avoid the issue!

Comment: It felt uncomfortable doing it round the way you mention, because it meant _updating_ an existing record from the `create` method in `line_items_contoller.rb` if the line_item already existed when the user tried to create it.

Comment: I'd add an `add_product` method to the `Order` model, and call that from your controller.

Comment: I think that's what I'll do, although I would still be curious to see a direct solution to the question posed - purely as a mental exercise!

Comment: In Rails 3 you can do `LineItem.group(:product_id, :size).sum(:quantity)` and it will return a hash `{[1, "small"] => 3, [1, "medium"] => 1, [2, "small"] => 1}`. I don't think there's a straightforward way to return instances of LineItem though, because, as they wouldn't correspond to records in the database, it doesn't really make sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so why do you want to group the `line_items` into a single virtual entity?

Seems easier to me to just created methods / scopes in the `Order` class that iterates through `line_items` and fetches the data **needed**. Again not sure what your end goal is here.

`Order` class:

```
def qty
  line_items.map{|li| li.quantity}.sum
end

def sizes
  line_items.map{|li| li.size}.uniq
end
```

Very simple examples if the order is loaded into memory already- hope that helps.
If DB searching / sorting is required then you could define a line_items module say in the lib directory and call methods directly off of the plural `line_items` calls... same could be done for 'Orders'

So `extend` your model association declaration:

```
has_many :line_items, :extend => LineItemsMethods, :dependent => :destroy
```

`LineItemsMethods` class:

```
def any_special_products?
  any? {|line_item| line_item.special_method}   
end
```

Scopes would work too of course... tried to keep it simple, hope thats helps.

---

#### Edit

I totally missed line two of your example where one `line_item` already had a quantity of 2. So I agree with the first answer: if you are going to have the user enter a quantity then be able to select that same product again; it **should** just update the existing quantity regardless if it is saved yet or not...

Comment: If you are just trying to display the line_items (you mentioned view) that is something else entirely...

Comment: changing and rewriting your whole answer from scratch isn't good practice. If you think your answer has become totally pointless somehow, vote to delete it. If it still has some information in it, even information that proves to be erroneous, just update it with the proper information, without losing the entire original answer.